# nslookup returns IP, but can ping hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, windows-server-2012-r2, reverse-dns

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server that I'm using for DNS.

My forward- and reverse lookup zones are correct and the problem is not with the DNS config (tested on the server as well as other Windows clients).

The problem is that I cannot ping a device by it's hostname on my Debian 8 server. When I run `nslookup client.domain.local` the DNS server returns the corresponding IP address, but it doesn't return the hostname when I run `nslookup xx.xx.xx.xx`. Furthermore, I cannot ping the hostname either, but I can ping the clients by their IPs.

resolv.conf on Debian 8:

```
domain domain.local
search domain.local
nameserver ip.of.server
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify the actual problem you're trying to solve and add some detail. When you say you can't ping them by name do you mean that the name isn't resolved or do you mean that the name is resolved but the ping fails?

Comment: It is a little unclear in the direction/location of your queries and if the failing points are DNS queries for your debian server or from your debian server. The use of nslookup instead of dig makes me think you are doing queries from a windows system? Both nslookup and dig will tell you in their standard output the nameserver they are using so you can verify if it is querying the correct server. Additionally you can specifically designate which DNS server to query so you can verify that the server is returning the desired response. The fact that nslookup xx.xx.xx.xx (the equivalent of 'dig -x

Comment: The fact that `nslookup xx.xx.xx.xx` (the equivalent of `dig -x nn.nn.nn.nn`) does not return a record points to the possibility that you do not have a PTR record defined, only an A record (which would explain why the lookup for the host name worked).

Not being able to ping the hostname (with the IP ping working) could be based on it pinging the wrong IP (do you have anything defined in the hosts file for the hostname?) or that it cannot resolve the hostname properly.

Comment: @pingyou Sorry for truncating your answer when I converted it to a comment, it is continued above in the second comment.